# Enterprise Application Project problema com dependências

Tags: java-ee, jboss, ejb, wildfly

Estou com problemas num projecto java ee.(Enterprise Application Project).

Estou a usar o servidor wildfly-8.0.0.Beta1.

A estrutura do meu projeto é a seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já coloquei no Web Project o EJB Project como dependência.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Contudo obtenho o seguinte warning:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    import javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedExecutorService;
    import javax.websocket.CloseReason;
    import javax.websocket.OnClose;
    import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
    import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
    import javax.websocket.Session;
    import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;
```

Como posso resolver este problema?

Já tentei de várias formas, mas com este problema quando corro o servlet funciona como o html estatico, mas quando faço @inject de um bean ele não consegue obter os valores da função pretendida.

Exemplo:

```
@Inject
Auto auto

auto.info();
```

O log do servidor é o seguinte neste momento:

```
  11:20:00,825 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.0.Final
    11:20:01,137 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.2.0.Beta2
    11:20:01,215 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015899: WildFly 8.0.0.Beta1 "WildFly" starting
    11:20:02,357 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found EEDemo-EXT.ear in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called EEDemo-EXT.ear.dodeploy
    11:20:02,381 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
    11:20:02,381 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-7) XNIO version 3.1.0.CR7
    11:20:02,381 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-7) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.1.0.CR7
    11:20:02,413 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBoss Remoting version 4.0.0.Beta1
    11:20:02,428 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
    11:20:02,428 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.17.SP1
    11:20:02,428 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
    11:20:02,444 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
    11:20:02,444 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 50) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
    11:20:02,460 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS012605: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main]
    11:20:02,491 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-14) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.1.0.Final)
    11:20:02,506 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) JBAS017502: Undertow 1.0.0.Beta17 starting
    11:20:02,506 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS017502: Undertow 1.0.0.Beta17 starting
    11:20:02,538 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
    11:20:02,538 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
    11:20:02,538 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010417: Started Driver service with driver-name = h2
    11:20:02,538 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
    11:20:02,631 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) JBAS017527: Creating file handler for path C:\Users\BrunoFontainha\Downloads\wildfly-8.0.0.Beta1/welcome-content
    11:20:02,647 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS017525: Started server default-server.
    11:20:02,647 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS017531: Host default-host starting
    11:20:02,788 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017519: Undertow HTTP listener default listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
    11:20:02,897 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\Users\BrunoFontainha\Downloads\wildfly-8.0.0.Beta1\standalone\deployments
    11:20:02,913 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "EEDemo-EXT.ear" (runtime-name: "EEDemo-EXT.ear")
    11:20:02,913 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999
    11:20:02,944 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
    11:20:03,053 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "null" (runtime-name: "EEDemo-EXTClient.jar")
    11:20:03,053 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-11) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "null" (runtime-name: "EEDemo-EXTConnector.rar")
    11:20:03,053 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-13) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "null" (runtime-name: "EEDemo-EXTWeb.war")
    11:20:03,053 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-16) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "null" (runtime-name: "EEDemo-EXTEJB.jar")
    11:20:03,085 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-14) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.2.1.Final
    11:20:03,210 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-11) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."EEDemo-EXT.ear"."EEDemo-EXTEJB.jar".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."EEDemo-EXT.ear"."EEDemo-EXTEJB.jar".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of subdeployment "EEDemo-EXTEJB.jar" of deployment "EEDemo-EXT.ear"
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.Beta1.jar:8.0.0.Beta1]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1944) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Beta2.jar:1.2.0.Beta2]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1877) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Beta2.jar:1.2.0.Beta2]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
    Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.getRequiredService(ServiceContainerImpl.java:668) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Beta2.jar:1.2.0.Beta2]
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.getDefaultResourceAdapterName(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:270)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processMessageBeans(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:152)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.processAnnotations(MessageDrivenComponentDescriptionFactory.java:80)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.processAnnotations(AnnotatedEJBComponentDescriptionDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:58)
        at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.deploy(AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:81)
        at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.Beta1.jar:8.0.0.Beta1]
        ... 5 more

    11:20:03,398 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "EEDemo-EXT.ear")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"EEDemo-EXT.ear\".\"EEDemo-EXTEJB.jar\".PARSE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"EEDemo-EXT.ear\".\"EEDemo-EXTEJB.jar\".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of subdeployment \"EEDemo-EXTEJB.jar\" of deployment \"EEDemo-EXT.ear\"
        Caused by: org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceNotFoundException: Service service jboss.ejb.default-resource-adapter-name-service not found"}}
    11:20:03,420 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) JBAS018559: Deployed "EEDemo-EXT.ear" (runtime-name : "EEDemo-EXT.ear")
    11:20:03,420 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
    JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.subunit."EEDemo-EXT.ear"."EEDemo-EXTEJB.jar".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."EEDemo-EXT.ear"."EEDemo-EXTEJB.jar".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of subdeployment "EEDemo-EXTEJB.jar" of deployment "EEDemo-EXT.ear"

    11:20:03,436 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
    11:20:03,436 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
    11:20:03,436 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: WildFly 8.0.0.Beta1 "WildFly" started (with errors) in 2982ms - Started 199 of 241 services (5 services failed or missing dependencies, 62 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
    11:20:03,655 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment null (runtime-name: EEDemo-EXTWeb.war) in 2ms
    11:20:03,655 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment null (runtime-name: EEDemo-EXTEJB.jar) in 2ms
    11:20:03,655 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-15) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment null (runtime-name: EEDemo-EXTConnector.rar) in 2ms
    11:20:03,655 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment null (runtime-name: EEDemo-EXTClient.jar) in 5ms
    11:20:03,655 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment EEDemo-EXT.ear (runtime-name: EEDemo-EXT.ear) in 7ms
    11:20:03,686 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018558: Undeployed "EEDemo-EXT.ear" (runtime-name: "EEDemo-EXT.ear")
    11:20:03,686 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report
    JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.subunit."EEDemo-EXT.ear"."EEDemo-EXTEJB.jar".PARSE

    11:20:08,459 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015003: Found EEDemo-EXT.ear in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called EEDemo-EXT.ear.dodeploy
```

Comment: Bruno, se ambas forem a mesma pergunta apague uma delas. Pode "editar" a pergunta em vez de criar uma nova.

Comment: Boas, neste momento encontro-me so com o problema no server, os outros ja foram resolvidos.

Comment: @BrunoFontainha Se já resolveu o problema com as dependências, você pode postar a solução em uma resposta nesta pergunta. Caso não queira, tem a opção também de remover a pergunta. Isso não vai afetar sua outra pergunta sobre o Wildfly.